Jpa repo executing without using/triggering from Spring boot
My application is developed with Spring Boot and Ext Js (Sencha). Currently, one of the dropdowns is displaying only 20 items, although there should be 21. I have enabled SQL logs and noticed that the query executes with 'limit ?' at the end. Despite removing every instance of the Repo usage, the query still executes with the limit.
//@Repository
public interface DeptCategory extends BaseJpaRepositoy<Category,Integer>{
}

Commenting out the @Repository annotation and renaming the interface to a random name seems to work. However, it only stops working when both lines in the interface are commented out.
//@Repository
//public interface DeptCategory extends BaseJpaRepositoy<Category,Integer>{
//}

I completely new Ext JS, did I have to check something from Ext JS for this concern?

Use logging and a debugger to find the code that executes the query. There are tons of ways to execute a query with or without repository.

I hope your question is based on what you see in the network tab. Without seeing the code, it could be that you are using a paging store, which limits the data to 20 items. But it could also be a filter, reader, or any kind of extra stuff you are doing to the incoming data. If you are sending limit and you only receive 20 items, its not ExtJS, but you are only requesting 20 items. So many possible ways to fix this. Please show us your ExtJS code for the store and the dropdown.

@JensSchauder, it's true that we can use repo interface without Repository annotation. here I wanted to identify from where the query/repo is been triggering. I have commented out all the usage of repo though I see the query logs in intillej console.
